# What's the difference between expo-yarn-workspaces.symlinks vs nohoist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using `expo-yarn-workspaces` to create a monorepo project containing React and React-native with expo. In this package, it is mentioned that I can create **symlinks** using `expo-yarn-workspaces`.symlinks key in `package.json`
Also for monorepo, I can use nohoist key in `package.json` to specify that the package should be installed inside local `node_modules`

I understand that in both the cases, location of my module is different, however I'm unable to understand the difference in terms of project build. Which method should be followed and what's the reason?
I didn't find enough documentation about both these techniques except some blogs which were giving very brief information just about usage. Can somebody please help?